# C++: makes variable or function public for same namespace, but private for different namespace

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make variables or functions to be public for multiple files in same namespace, but private for different namespace?

For example:

a1.cpp

```
namespace A
{
    int distance = 10;
}
```

a2.cpp

```
namespace A
{
    extern int distance;
    void f() { std::cout << distance; }    // OK! I need this access.
}
```

b.cpp

```
namespace A
{
    extern int distance;
}

namespace B
{
    void f() { std::cout << A::distance; } // I would like to prevent this access! 
}
```

Comment: I don't think namespaces have _any_ sort of access controls, much less ones at this level of granularity.

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: I think C++20's modules do something like this. Symbols not exported by the module are "private"

Comment: @Caleth It seems that is what I want! But, unfortunately, major compilers do not fully support C++20's modules.

Answer (score 1):

No, namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries. And identifiers outside the namespace can ACCESS the members by using the fully qualified name for each identifier. So you cannot prevent outsider access variable within namespace.